# Why can't the file scanner detect all new lines?

Tags: python, file, io

I am trying to create a bedwars stats overlay, however the scanner can't detect all the new players that have joined.

If two or more players join at once into a lobby, it only detects the last person who joined shown in the Hypixel chat.

I tried creating a queue system, which involves sequencing lines in order to help detect any missing lines, but it didn't work. I think it might be a performance issue since I have requests happening further down the while loop.

Here is the code

```
while True:
    with open(lunar_path, "r") as f:
        try:
            line_total = fix_line(f.readlines()[-1])
            if last_line != line_total:
                os.system("cls")
                line_list.append(line_total)
            line = line_list[0]
            if "has joined" in line:
                if not first_joined:
                    users_name = line.split(" ")[0]
                    first_joined = True
                if round_joined:
                    if line.split(" ")[0] == users_name:
                        player_dict = {}
                        player_list = []
                    elif line.split(" ")[0] not in player_list:
                        player_list.append(line.split(" ")[0])
                if not round_joined:
                    round_joined = True
```

Comment: Not sure what the code is trying to do, but you are opening/reading/closing the file in an endless loop. That's not very efficient. You might want to find a library that uses the OS to monitor files. Or, at least add a delay in the loop.

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of reading the last line, I keep an index for the last line read and loop after that through every new line created afterwards.

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it below in the Answer section.